# In App Localization iOS 8/9, English Arabic

Tags: localization, ios9, arabic-support

I want to keep my app in one of the regions and I want to localize the app without changing the native language or region settings, specifically for iOS 9, is there any way to localize the app without changing ios system settings?

Answer (score 1):

```
 [NSBundle setLanguage:@"ar"];
```

in the main.m before @autoreleasepool

```
#import "NSBundle+Language.h"
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static const char _bundle=0;

@interface BundleEx : NSBundle
@end

@implementation BundleEx
-(NSString*)localizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key value:(NSString *)value table:(NSString *)tableName
 {
     NSBundle* bundle=objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &_bundle);
     return bundle ? [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:value table:tableName] : [super localizedStringForKey:key value:value table:tableName];
 }
 @end

 @implementation NSBundle (Language)
 +(void)setLanguage:(NSString*)language
 {
     static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
     dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^
              {
                  object_setClass([NSBundle mainBundle],[BundleEx class]);
              });
objc_setAssociatedObject([NSBundle mainBundle], &_bundle, language ? [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:language ofType:@"lproj"]] : nil, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
    }
     @end
```

Comment: Please describe in detail how your code could be used for the questioner. Thank you.

Comment: @LeonidGlanz it's like choosing specific resource files for a specific language forced in the beginning by developer 

in this case the specific language is arabic